# dateadd function won't work in SAS sql

Tags: sql, sas, teradata, proc

I am migrating the queries written in teradata to `SAS` tool. 
Below statement is throwing an error Function `DATEADD` could not be located:

```
ct.MaturityDate < dateadd(dd, 30,getdate())
```

I googled and found intck works here. But, not getting an idea how to use it here.

Comment: Depends a bit. If you are in SAS internal proc sql environment you can just try `ct.MaturityDate < date() + 30`

Comment: I don't think teradata has `DATEADD` and `getdate()`functions in first place :-)

Comment: Yep, `dateadd` & `getdate` are SQL Server syntax, not Teradata.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date calculations in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209121/date-calculations-in-sas)

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is add 30 days to the current date you can, as @pingulf suggests, simply use

```
ct.maturitydate < date() + 30
```

or

```
ct.maturitydate < today() + 30
```

`today()` and `date()` being aliases of the same function.

This solution only works for days. To do the same with months or years you would indeed use `intnx` not `intck`. In your case:

```
ct.MaturityDate < intnx('day',date(),30)
```

More information on the `intnx` function on the [SAS support website](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=fedsqlref&docsetTarget=n1mtvizfg1y0g9n1wslqgjxseh0i.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)