# How to get Number of days between two dates in SAS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas

I have a table named case_DataTable_d in which column name `value_dt` have different date values. I want get number of day difference between that date and date of today.

This is my code

```
proc sql noprint;
 create table daystoOverdue_list as
 select distinct business_object_rk , DateDiff(DAY, value_dt, Today()) as value_dt
 from case_DataTable_d as tbl
 where tbl.cust_field_nm eq "x_case_dte_dd"
 and datepart(tbl.value_dt) < today();
quit;
```

I'm having errors that

Day is not any column name

function DateDiff could not be located.

Comment: What about `intck('dtday', value_dt, Today())`?

Comment: dtday is giving values as 21162 for dates who has difference of 2 days

Comment: `'dtday'` is for datetimes.  How is `value_dt` stored?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date calculations in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209121/date-calculations-in-sas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateDiff is not a valid SAS function.  Try `intck`:

```
%let today=%sysfunc(date());
proc sql noprint;
 create table daystoOverdue_list as
 select distinct business_object_rk 
    , intck('DAY', datepart(tbl.value_dt), &today) as value_dt
 from case_DataTable_d as tbl
 where tbl.cust_field_nm eq "x_case_dte_dd"
 and datepart(tbl.value_dt) < &today;
```

This function returns the number of interval boundaries of a given kind that lie between two dates, times, or datetime values (see [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1md4mx2crzfaqn14va8kt7qvfhr.htm)).

Comment: I don't know why but It's only giving me a period . means a missing value

Comment: And there are lots of records who due date is less then today

Comment: My bad - `today()` isn't a SAS function either.  Should be `date()`.

Comment: also, running the function on the where clause is inefficient - will fire for every record.  Better to make a constant and use that via a macro variable.

Comment: Still not working but thank you for giving your precious time.

Comment: Try changing this `intck('DAY', DATEPART(value_dt), &today)` . You're mixing date and datetime variables is likely why you're running into these issues. Make sure everything is date or datetime and use the appropriate intervals, ie DAY if date, DTDAY if datetime.

Comment: aah - should have deduced that from the `datepart` function in the OP's example.  Thanks @Reeza!