# How to categorize a date by decade in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with many dates in them. I want to categorize these dates into a new column that organizes them by decade (1980s, 1990s, etc).

I have a good idea on how to use IF, AND, and ELSE statements to accomplish this, but I don't know how to have SAS extract the year and only the year from the date to apply it to the conditional logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use multipliers and the `intnx()` function as well.

Using Allan's sample data...

```
data want;
  set have;
  decade=year(intnx('year10.',dateval,0,'beginning'));
run;
```

The `intnx()` part of the code returns the date corresponding to the start of the decade, then we just take the year portion from it.

The `year10.` parameter tells it we want to work with decades, the `0` parameter means shift the date supplied to the current decade, and the `beginning` parameter tells it to return the date corresponding to the beginning of the decade.

If you're not familiar with using `intnx()` to perform date calculations in SAS see here for a quick primer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11211180/214994

Answer (score 0):

No need for conditional logic - can use a combination of the `year()` and `floor()` functions with some simple arithmetic:

```
data have;
infile cards;
input dateval date9.;
cards;
01JAN2004
08FEB1996
07MAR1987
14SEP1982
;run;

data want;
  set have;
  decade=floor(year(dateval)/10)*10;
run;
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: I try to apply this to my code and get the error

 ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator.
 
 ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.
 
 ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

highlighted for the semicolon. Am I applying this operation correctly?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing how you applied it!  Can you paste your exact code?