# SAS CATS function returning periods instead of numbers

Tags: date, sas, concatenation

I am attempting to concatenate two fields. I want to show the month and year from a date.

The two functions returns results properly when used separate outside of the cats function.

Example: 2/14/2019

MONTH(APP.SUBMITTEDON) returns 2

YEAR(APP.SUBMITTEDON) returns 2019

But when I try to concatenate them together like below, it returns ./. and not 2/2019.

CATS(MONTH(APP.SUBMITTEDON),'/',YEAR(APP.SUBMITTEDON)) AS MONTH_YEAR

Thoughts?

Full code is:

```
proc sql;
create table COUNTS AS
select distinct COUNT.APP_ID AS COUNT
,CATS(MONTH(APP.SUBMITTEDON),'/',YEAR(APP.SUBMITTEDON)) AS MONTH_YEAR
from APP
GROUP BY MONTH_YEAR;
```

Comment: There is no table alias named `APP` in your SQL query, I assume you made a mistake when posting the code.

Comment: That's likely the issue, show the log please. CATS() will do automatic conversions otherwise.

Comment: Apologies. You are correct and I have updated the post. The only portion of the log pertaining to these fields are; NOTE: Invalid argument to function MONTH. Missing values may be generated.
NOTE: Invalid argument to function YEAR. Missing values may be generated.

Comment: Without knowing more my guess is one of two things.  1) It could be a typo: Triple check that the variable names in the table match the code (make sure you're looking at variable names and not variable labels).  2) The source table contains missing values.  Open up the source table and make sure it actually contains the values you expect.

Comment: Now there is no alias of `count` for the variable named `count.app_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Month and year functions return INT

you need char

```
put(month(APP.SUBMITTEDON),z2.)
```

or use format monyy. to change your date display to month year.

Comment: CATS() is supposed to do automatic conversion according to the best format and the documentation. `If item is numeric, then its value is converted to a character string by using the BESTw. format. In this case, SAS does not write a note to the log.`

Comment: Using the above still produces the ./.
CATS(Put(MONTH(APP.SUBMITTEDON),z2.),'/',Put(YEAR(APP.SUBMITTEDON),z2.)) AS MONTH_YEAR

Comment: I was separating the month and year out instead of using the format function below because I have a table matrix which shows the last day of each month. I would then concate that into the formula above. 

Ideally, I want to turn the date 2/14/2019 into 2/28/2019. Or 3/05/2019 to 3/31/2019.

Comment: @user1590497 Posting this as a comment as it wasn't part of the original question.  But to find the last day in a given month you can simply use the `intnx()` function.  Take a look at this question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11211180/214994 .  In your case, you would do something like: `last_day_of_month = intnx('month', your_date_value, 0, 'end');`

Comment: @RobertPenridge. I had already tried that but wasn't getting the results I was looking for (just returned blank) so I changed my approach to what's in this post. When using the above a blank value is returned. When looking at my table through the contents procedure it states this field is in number type in datetime25.6 format.

Comment: @user1590497 Ahh ok.  So the problem is your field is a `datetime` value, not a `date` value.  You need to wrap the variable with the `datepart()` function before trying to apply the `month()` or `year()` function to it, and it should work fine.

Comment: @RobertPenridge Thank you sir! I've been banging my head on this forever! For S&Gs I attempted to use this with the intnx function, it  returns a strange value now, which  isn't in date format at all. Thoughts?

Comment: @user1590497 Date values in SAS are just stored as numeric values (specifically, the number of days since 1/1/1960).  So a numeric value of 1 in SAS, when formatted with a date format would show as 2nd Jan 1960. e.g. `data _null_; x = 1; put x date9.; run;`.  So don't make the mistake of confusing the formatted appearance of a date, as the actual value.  If you look at today's date in SAS (6/14/2019) then the actual numeric value stored in the variable is 21714. E.g. `data _null_; x = date(); put x; run;`. So it sounds like you simply need to format your variable to see it as a date.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the fact that this is a SAS date and use that.

```
proc sql;
create table COUNTS AS
select distinct COUNT.APP_ID AS COUNT
, put(datepart(app.submittedon), yymms10.) AS MONTH_YEAR
from APPLICANT
GROUP BY MONTH_YEAR;
quit;
```

EDIT: Modified to deal with a data time variable.

Answer (score 0):

That combination of functions is correct.  You have something else going on that isn't listed in your question:

Create some sample data:

```
data have;
  do date='31jan2019'd to '1feb2019'd;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Test running a basic query against it using `cats()`, `month()`, and `year()`:

```
proc sql ;
  create table counts as
  select date,
         month(date) as month,
         year(date) as year,
         cats(month(date),'/',year(date)) as month_year1,
         put(date,yymms7.) as month_year2
         put(date,yymmn6.) as month_year3
  from have
  ;
quit;
```

I also threw in some alternative ways to represent date variables as a month/year using various formats.

Finally, it is a really bad idea to use both a `distinct` clause and a `group by` clause in the same SQL query.  Double check what you are intending to do here because as it stands that query may not give expected results and it's intention would be difficult to ascertain.

Answer (score 0):

The CATS() function will use the character assigned to the `MISSING` option for missing numeric values.  You can change the missing option to a space instead and then the periods will not appear.

But from comments on some of the other answers it looks like your real problem is that you are dealing with a DATETIME variable and not a DATE variable.  SAS stores DATE values as the number of days since 1960 and DATETIME values as the number of seconds.  Functions like MONTH() and YEAR() will not work right when given a number in seconds instead of days.

Also there is no need to pull out the month and year and paste them back together as SAS already has formats that will return that string for you.  For example you might want to use the `MONYY` format (or `DTMONYY` for datetime values).

```
create table COUNTS AS
select put(submittedon,dtmonyy.) as month_year
     , count( distinct APP_ID) AS COUNT
from APP
GROUP BY MONTH_YEAR
;
```

Note that you might want to use a format that places YEAR before MONTH so that the values of your new character variable will sort properly.

```
create table COUNTS AS
select substr(put(datepart(submittedon),yymmdds10.),1,7) as month_year
     , count( distinct APP_ID) AS COUNT
from APP
GROUP BY MONTH_YEAR
;
```