# How to format a variable in a SAS dataset created in Lua with sas.ds_write as a datetime value?

Tags: datetime, lua, sas, format

I collect data into `Lua` tables that I export to `SAS` datasets with `sas.ds_write`. Some columns contain strings that represent timestamps in the format "14OCT19:09:12:52". I succeed to convert them to a SAS datetime value, but in SAS, they arrive as numbers without a format.

Is there a way to specify a number in Lua is a DateTime value?

Comment: Does your question about how to convert numbers into datetime? Or you want to force set format to column? some code that can help us to understand each other)) `data l;/*format dt datetime32.;*/ dt = "14OCT19:09:12:52"dt; run;` will give you `1886663572`. If you remove comment , the result will be `14OCT2019:09:12:52`.

Comment: Take a look at vasjas response on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11209685/214994  .  As Sanek mentioned, you will need to apply a format to the SAS column in order for the numeric value to be visually represented as a human readable datetime.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to format values before export?

Example:

**Dataset**

(imagine the result is your data exported from the Lua table)

```
DATA mytest;
    INPUT dates;
    CARDS;
1886663572
1886763572
1886863572
;
RUN;
```

Result:

[image]

**Format values**

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE myresults AS
    SELECT PUT(dates, datetime19.) AS formatted_dates
    FROM mytest
    ;
RUN;
```

Result:

[image]

Now, notice the output values are character-type, you could use something like [this](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/convert-character-date-time-string-to-SAS-format-datetime/td-p/383427) to cast them into datetime data type.

Comment: This is a question on proc lua

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood then. I thought you were exporting your data from a Lua table to a SAS dataset (which can be formatted as I did in my example). If not, then maybe this could help: https://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html